# Maximal number of adjacent bits flipping only one

Tags: debugging, language-agnostic, pseudocode

This problem came up on an online coding test pre-interview. I've attempted to completely change the scenario & any inconsequential information so as to avoid anyone taking said test locating this post.

The problem involves a string of bytes. You have been asked to find the maximal count of adjacent pairs if you can flip one bit.

ie 101110 would have 4 adjacent pairs if you flipped the second bit.

I was given code which appeared to solve the problem, and asked fix it by changing up to three lines. Unfortunately I couldn't find the bug. Its been frustrating me for a while now..

The supplied code (compiled and ran on supplied example fine)

```
int sol(int[] Arr):
    int l = len(Arr)
    int t = 0
    for i 0..(l-2):
        if A[i] = A[i+1]:
            t += 1
    int r = 0
    for i 0..(l-1):
        int c = 0
        if i > 0:
            if A[i-1] != A[i]:
                c++
            else:
                c--
        if i < (l-1):
            if A[i+1] != A[i]:
                c++
            else:
                c--
         r = Max(r, c);
 return t+r
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add an appropriate language tag.

Comment: The test site allows you to answer in several languages. The above provided is really pseudocode, deliverately written not to mirror any of the available languages too much.

Comment: OK - you said in your question that it "compiled and ran" - hence my suggestion. You could probably add a `language-agnostic` tag instead then.

Comment: Thanks :) Done. It should be trivial to convert that to the language of your choice.
I tried to keep everything as different to the supplied problem as possible because well, whats the point of an online test if you can just google it!

Answer (score 0):

To find a bug or and exploit i may try to understand the code first :

first loop count the number of pair in the sequence ("00" or "11") in t

```
for i 0..(l-2):
    if A[i] = A[i+1]:
        t += 1
```

then second loop look for specific sequences :

1. "101" or "010" then c = 2
2. "01" or "10" then c = 1 (only when looking at first or last bit)
3. other sequences c = 0 or -1 or -2

and keep the higher value between c and r in r so any value of c less than 0 is irrelevant.

```
int r = 0
for i 0..(l-1):
    int c = 0
    if i > 0:
        if A[i-1] != A[i]:
            c++
        else:
            c--
    if i < (l-1):
        if A[i+1] != A[i]:
            c++
        else:
            c--
     r = Max(r, c);
```

To find a bug you can simply exploit the first loop parsing a long "11001100110011001100..." sequence, you will find a value of half the sequence length divided by 2 when the real value should be 2.

This may only be an half answer because i couldn't find a fix changing only 3 line but maybe as you changed the code you also changes the number of lines some instruction take or the order of few lines.

I feel like the fix involve merging the two loop and using t in the max with few other changes but it would make more than 3 lines changed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the amount of adjacents can go down. E.g.: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0). That's 5 adjancies. If you flip any of them, the amount drops down to 4, but the algorithm you presented does only allow for the amount to go up, because the starting value of `c` is zero, and you are `max()`ing it.